# Function of Matrices with the numerial Range on a Disk

Tags: calculus, matrices, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

[image]

Hello, iam currently reading a paper and iam having trouble with this proof. Its really short and he doesnt really explain alot. I get how he concludes from $\Vert T \Vert \leq 1$ to the result, but i dont really know how he even starts to evaluate the Operator Norm of $H$ and $H^{-1}$, that he just writes down.

$M_d(D)$ is the set of all Operators $A$ where the numerical Range is subset of the Disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand how $H$ is defined, using the continuous functional calculus. Remember, $B$ is a Hermitian matrix, which implies it is orthogonally diagonalisable, and its spectrum (i.e. the set of eigenvalues) is a finite subset of $\Bbb{R}$. That is to say, there is some unitary matrix $V$ and real number $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ such that
$$B = V^* \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)V.$$
Taking $g(B)$ just means
$$g(B) = V^* \operatorname{diag}(g(\lambda_1), \ldots, g(\lambda_n))V.$$
It's a little boring in the case of matrices; this continuous functional calculus is more exciting in general C$^*$ algebras.

The next thing to remember is that, given a square matrix $C$ and unitary $W$ of the same size, then both $CW$ and $WC$ have the same operator norm. The reason is that $v \mapsto Wv$ is an isometry, as
$$\|Wv\|^2 = (Wv)^*Wv = v^*W^*Wv = v^*v = \|v\|^2.$$
So,
$$\|C\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|Cv\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|WCv\| = \|WC\|$$
and since $W$ is invertible, with $W^{-1}$ being also unitary,
$$\|C\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|Cv\| = \sup_{\|Wv\| = 1} \|CWv\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|CWv\| = \|CW\|.$$
Therefore,
$$\|H\| = \|g(B)\| = \|\operatorname{diag}(g(\lambda_1), \ldots, g(\lambda_n))\| = \max(|g(\lambda_1)|, \ldots, |g(\lambda_n)|).$$
Looking at $g$, we can see that $g(\lambda_i) \in [1, 2]$, and so $|g(\lambda_i)| = g(\lambda_i)$. So, from this we see that
$$\|H\| = \max(g(\lambda_1), \ldots, g(\lambda_n)) \le 2,$$
and
$$\|H^{-1}\| = \max(g(\lambda_1)^{-1}, \ldots, g(\lambda_n)^{-1}) = \min(g(\lambda_1), \ldots, g(\lambda_n))^{-1} \le 1^{-1} = 1.$$
For $\sin(B)H$ and $H^{-1}\cos(B)$, we note that $\sin(B)$, $\cos(B)$, and $H$ are all continuous functions of $B$. So, $\sin(B)H$ is the result of applying $x \mapsto \sin(x) \cdot g(x)$ to $B$, and similarly $H^{-1} \cos(B)$ is the result of applying $x \mapsto \cos(x)/g(x)$ to $B$. Note that
$$\sin(x)g(x) = \sin(x) \max\{1, |\cos(x)|\} = \begin{cases}\sin(x) \\ 2\sin(x)\cos(x) \\ -2\sin(x)\cos(x) \end{cases} = \begin{cases}\sin(x) \\ \sin(2x) \\ -\sin(2x). \end{cases}$$
Note, I omitted where the above cases hold. It doesn't matter in the end: $\sin(x)g(x)$ must take one of these three values, all of which lie in $[-1, 1]$. We can therefore conclude that $|\sin(x)g(x)| \le 1$, and it follows as before that $\|\sin(B)g(B)\| \le 1$.

Next, we examine $\cos(x) / g(x)$. Here the cases do matter. We have:
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{g(x)} = \begin{cases} \cos(x) & \text{if } |\cos(x)| \le \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\cos(x)}{2\cos(x)} & \text{if } \cos(x) \ge \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\cos(x)}{-2\cos(x)} & \text{if } \cos(x) \le -\frac{1}{2} \end{cases} = \begin{cases} \cos(x) & \text{if } |\cos(x)| \le \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } \cos(x) \ge \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & \text{if } \cos(x) \le -\frac{1}{2}. \end{cases}$$
It is clear that $2|\cos(x) / g(x)| \le 1$, hence
$$2\|H^{-1}\cos(B)\| \le 1.$$
The final $\|T\| \le 1$ comes from submultiplicativity:
\begin{align*}
\|T\| &= \|H^{-1}AH\| \\
&= \|2H^{-1}\cos(B)U\sin(B)H\| \\
&\le 2\|H^{-1}\cos(B)\| \|U\| \|\sin(B)H\| \\
&\le 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: First of all, thank you for your very detailed anwser it helped me alot. 
I have one question left regarding sin(x)g(x). How do you get to the negative case? If it takes the maximum from 1 and 2cos(x), shouldnt it be impossible to go negative?

Comment: The negative case comes from where $\cos(x) < -\frac{1}{2}$, and so $g(x) = 2|\cos(x)| = -2\cos(x)$.

Comment: Ah i get it, so its not actually negativ, its just the case distinction of the absolute value

Comment: Another question came up, when i looked at the sources that he provided. For [1] to be true, he needs the condition, that the spectral radius is less then one. So the proof is no problem on the unit disk, but what about other disk. I know that you could shift  the matrix and the function, such that:
$\hat{f}(z) = f(\hat{z} + rz)$ and $\hat{A} = (A - zI)/r$ with  $\sup_{\mathcal{D}_1(0)}\vert\hat{f} \vert= \sup_{\mathcal{D}_r(\hat{z})}\vert f \vert $
But iam not quite sure why, or how that has any impact on the spectral radius.

Comment: @Bergelmirr "Ah i get it, so its not actually negativ, its just the case distinction of the absolute value" Yes, sort of. The thing is, it actually could well be negative, due to the (sometimes negative) factor of $\sin(x)$. But, the $-$ sign in the cases does not correspond to where the function is negative or positive. The latter two cases are sometimes negative and sometimes positive.

Comment: As for the follow-up question, I would suggest posting that as a new question. Make sure to link back to this question for context. I'm not certain what the $\hat{}$ refers to here, so make sure you mention that in the new question.